# d3.js geo worldmap - merge russia (shift small part from the left next to america to the right)

Tags: d3.js, geo, topojson, d3.geo

I created a simple worldmap with d3 as you can see here: http://bl.ocks.org/wiesson/ef18dba71256d526eb42

[image: shift small part to the right]

Is there a simple way to shift the small part of russia (as illustrated in the picture) to the right, without creating a new topojson? If not, any other idea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay, the answer was straightforward. As explained in the api docs, the method [rotate](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#rotation) can turn the map.
So, `rotate([-11, 0])` "rotated" the map in the position I was looking for.

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator().scale(width / 2 / Math.PI)
    .rotate([-11, 0])
    .translate([(width) / 2, height * 1.35 / 2])
    .precision(.1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been searching for days on end!

Comment: You're a time saver! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you also figured out how to remove a line which appears there after rotate?

Comment: @GeorgiyBukharov You should have topology coordinates file. In that file you can find that small part of Russia as a separate country. Just move those topology coordinates to "Russia" MultiPolygon object. This is usually defined in JSON file. After that you should have Russia merged without line between them.