# How do I rotate a D3 topojson geomap to shift small part from the left next to america to the right?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a D3 based tool for R, and I don't get how to move the little piece of Russia on the left side of the map to the right, or in other words I want to have a "continuous" map to avoid shading all of it.

I saw this but it doesn't work [d3.js geo worldmap - merge russia (shift small part from the left next to america to the right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34297690/d3-js-geo-worldmap-merge-russia-shift-small-part-from-the-left-next-to-americ)

Do you have any ideas? my viz is here https://github.com/pachadotdev/d3po/blob/main/javascript/src/viz/methods/coords.js

[image]
[image]
[image]